# ngRepeat filter based on scope variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-digest

I have the following use of ng-repeat for displaying blog posts:

```
data-ng-repeat="post in posts | filter: {category: filterCategory} | limitTo:12 ">
```

'filterCategory' is a scope variable, which I change with ng-click on a set of list items:

```
<li class="filter" ng-repeat="post in (posts | unique: 'category._id' )" ng-click="setFilterCategory(post.category._id)">
```

controlled by the following:

```
 $scope.setFilterCategory = function(id) {
        $scope.filterCategory = id;
 }
```

The problem is, when a user clicks on one of those list items and **setFilterCategory()** changes the **filterCategory** in the scope, for a moment all posts are exhibited (as if there were no filters), then the filter is applied. I would like to avoid this transition and go straight from the previous filter to the next filter. Is there anything I can do?

I assume this has to do with the digest cycle, but I am not experienced enough to state exactly what should I change, if anything.

**Edit #1:**
I tried to reproduce in a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/igorauad/w4mkny0e/), but haven't had success. It works ok in this fiddle, while in my application it takes longer. I don't know if it makes a difference, but in my application I am loading *posts* from a resource, while in the fiddle they are statically declared.

Comment: able to create a fiddle we can play with?

Answer (score -2):

Try with this if you problem is with scope with delay.

```
 $scope.setFilterCategory = function(id) {
      $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.filterCategory = id;
      });
 }
```

if you still see the problem, can you create plunker or JSfiddle or any

Comment: Thank you @Dilip. This could not solve the problem, it says "$apply already in progress". Here is the JSFiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/igorauad/w4mkny0e/embedded/result/](http://jsfiddle.net/igorauad/w4mkny0e/embedded/result/) Strangely enough, the fiddle doesn't have the problem I mentioned, I don't know exactly how to reproduce it.

Comment: Sorry, the link is [http://jsfiddle.net/igorauad/w4mkny0e/](http://jsfiddle.net/igorauad/w4mkny0e/)

Comment: You forgot the '$', the `$scope` method is `$apply`, and using it in a controller will often throw [$digest already in progress error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog).